# Samsung Galaxy Buds immense RAM requirement

Tags: ram, android-wear, earphone, earpiece

I was about to buy some Samsung Galaxy Buds but then saw in the system requirements that they required **1.5GB of ram to operate!**

"Compatibility" section under "specifications"
https://checkout.telstra.com.au/consumer/rewards/headphones-speakers/145

I'm using an old S7 Android Galaxy phone. Right now it is using 2.9GB out of it's available 3.5GB of RAM just with the apps I have open.

I'm worried that my phone doesn't have enough ram to use the headphones.

Do the ear buds really require 1.5GB of RAM to operate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is just a misunderstanding:

The Galaxy Buds don't need 1.5 GB RAM free (nor do they use 1.5 GB RAM). The requirement means that your Android device needs to have at least 1.5 GB RAM installed in total. How much is free at the moment is of no concern (this is managed by Android).

Therefore older devices and low-cost devices with 1.0 GB or even 512MB RAM are officially not supported.

Your Galaxy S7 has 4GB RAM in total, hence you are fully compliant with the requirements.

Comment: My new headphones are on their way!  Thanks for the clarification 

Answer (score 0):

Your buds shouldn't ever need 1.5GB of RAM, since it's just a bluetooth device that relays information from your phone. If your device supports Bluetooth, then it's a given that it will be supported.